# Как запретить доступ к файлу напрямую?

Tags: .htaccess, php

Подскажите, как можно сделать так, чтобы файл можно вызвать только из другого файла, если он включен в него, но не по прямой?

Например, только так

```
<?php include ("modern.php"); ?>
```

Но не чисто из строки браузера modern.php? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
$block = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (strlen($block) > 1) {
?>
   <!-- Содержание страницы -->
    <?php
} else {
    echo "<script>location.href='http://site.ru/index.php';</script>";
}
?
```

Comment: WTF?
Я спокойно могу послать любой реферер. Неправильная защита.  
@dogmar и @klopp пишут правильно. Особо важные файлы, тип логина/пароля к БД можно вынести за корень.

Answer (score 3):

index.php:

```
define( 'FROM_INDEX', 1 );
include( 'modern.php' );
```

modern.php:

```
if( !defined('FROM_INDEX') ) exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете изначально устанавливать константу либо переменную в том файле, в котором вызываете modern.php, а в самом modern.php проверять её наличие.

Comment: Выкиньте лучше краткий примерчик!

Answer (score 1):

Никогда не понимал, зачем использовать константы, писать ненужные условия.

Создаете папку, в которой лежат ваши файлы, которые подключаются только из другого файла. В эту папку кидаете файл `.htaccess`, в котором прописано `deny all`.

Даже в мануале *PHP* написано, не использовать такие вот конструкции: `define( 'FROM_INDEX', 1 );`

Т.к. это какой-то костыль!

Comment: **αλεχολυτ** - Такая фишка не работает: > .htaccess, в котором прописано deny from all.